# Improving scroll effect with one side scroll and the other change image based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, styles

I created this scroll effect, where `div` is divided into left and right side - **left side** contains of images, that change based on scroll position and it's fixed and **right side** is scrolling content.

**This is my idea:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-effect-forked-ssi3x?file=/src/index.css

*To describe the sandbox* - you can see that my scroll effect works, but **right div** scrolls only when mouse is on that **right div**, what I need is that content of that **right div** will scroll down also when mouse is on **left div**

I tried to make the whole container's position `fixed` so it doesn't move, but it did not work. Is there a way how to achieve it?

**Here is example of what I would like it to be like:**

*(starts with STEP 1)*
https://honextmaterial.com/process/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal in React, you need a combination of some CSS and the JS scroll event. First, assign `position: sticky` to the element you need to be fixed when it's about to leave the viewport. Then, using a React ref, you access the scroll position of the scrollable div and use that logic to set your image source (you should avoid accessing the DOM directly with `getElementById` in React).

Here's a [working codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-effect-forked-1fsm1?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: I had no idea of doing it this way! Seems way cleaner and makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this basically with only CSS. You could make the right (scrollable) side overlap the left side with `position: absolute`. Then the whole area is scrollable. After that you'd change the width of the inner element to 60% and you'd visually have the same output as before. I changed your `codesandbox` accordingly: https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-effect-forked-55qsf

The only downside is, that the left side is not clickable, scrollable etc. anymore. If you want to keep HTML & CSS like before, you'd have to capture the `scroll-event` and run some JavaScript code.